Why are my Laravel route model bindings returning a 404 error?
I'm working on a Laravel project and using route model binding to automatically inject model instances into my routes. However, I'm encountering an issue where some routes return a 404 error even though the model
instance exists in the database.
I have defined a route in my web.php file like this:
Route::get('/posts/archived/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show']);
PostController
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }
}

Despite having records in the posts table, when I navigate to /posts/1 or any other valid ID, I get a 404 error. I've verified that the records exist in the database

The route you specified listens for urls like /posts/archived/1

Check your Route. It is incorrect. You should hit this route: /posts/archived/1
OR
you should change your original route to: /posts/{post} in web.php
